# Assignment to pointer to structure from pointer within a different structure type

Tags: c, pointers, structure, variable-assignment

I am currently trying to assign a pointer to a structure called totheright (which is a linked list node). The pointer to the structure/list is currently within another structure called rectangles. I am encountering an error when I attempt to do so.

```
currect->right = malloc(sizeof(totheright));
righthead = current->right;
```

The following are the declarations in function:

```
rect *currect = NULL;
totheright *righthead = NULL;
```

Structure definitions in header:

```
typedef struct _totheright {
    int rect;
    struct _totheright *right;
} totheright;

typedef struct _rect {
    int thisrect;
    struct totheright *right;
    int left;
    double width;
    double height;
    double xcord;
    double ycord;
    struct _rect *next;
} rect;
```

Comment: `righthead = current->right;` should be `righthead = currect->right;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `right` in structure `rect` should not have `struct` before `totheright` or `struct _totheright` should be used:

```
typedef struct _rect {
    int thisrect;
    //struct totheright *right; // was
    totheright *right; // fixed
    //struct _totheright *right; // that would be ok as well
    int left;
    double width;
    double height;
    double xcord;
    double ycord;
    struct _rect *next;
} rect;
```

Comment: That fixed my problem! I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you, Michael!